# There is better solution than simple port forwarding from my router to my internal system?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, sshd, dynamic-ip

If I forward a port from my router to one of my internal system's ssh port, I start to get messages from the system of attempts with invalid password, invalid user, etc.  I assume that someone is trying to break the user and password combination.  With ssh, I can set it so that a login is not even valid and only with a key can someone log in.  But I still get the messages.  Perhaps there is some option on sshd that would help that I'm not aware of.

The reason for the forwarded port is so I can gain access to my system at home when I travel.  The home network is inside a Spectrum cable network so I have no-ip account so that when I travel I can ssh to `router.foodog.house` which goes to the IP address that my home system is currently using.

But I'm wondering if there isn't a whole other approach that can be implemented.  One thought is to have the no-ip address be for my laptop and then a process on one of the home systems could ssh to my laptop creating a return tunnel that the laptop could then use to get back into the home system.

Before I go off and implement this concept I thought I would ask if this has already been done and nicely packaged up somewhere or are there other standard ways solving this problem.

TL; DR - What are the alternative approaches to logging into a home system while traveling other than forwarding a port from the home system's router to one of its internal systems?

Comment: VPN is a better alternative to port forwarding.

Comment: @John - You still need to port forward to use VPN.  Which will then log attempts to log into the VPN. There is no solution to "port forwarding", if you are behind a NAT, because the gateway or router must know where to send the traffic on that port.

Comment: The VPN solutions I have used open ports for VPN use only and with encrypted traffic.

Comment: The idea to reverse the no-ip address will not work, because your laptop will not be reachable while traveling (without port-forwarding the other direction). If you change the SSH port, you'll dramatically reduce the amount of noise you get from the public. There are some other good suggestions here: https://tailscale.com/learn/ssh-security-best-practices-protecting-your-remote-access-infrastructure/ . Using a cloud service as middle-man is a simple way to avoid opening up your home network (but generally at cost).

Comment: @John - You still have to forward the port to the machine running the VPN server. Reverse proxy might avoid port forwarding but not a VPN server like OpenVPN

Comment: In the router, the port has the VPN APP that purely for the VPN.  That is, only VPN has access to it. As far as I know , that port is otherwise closd to normal traffic.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Yea.  I thought about the problem with the reverse of the no-ip address after I posted the note.  When traveling the laptop will be behind some NAT somewhere which will block access.  I do have a host in the cloud.  I think I’m going to have a process inside my home ssh to the cloud host with a tunnel.  Then when I’m remote, I can ssh to the cloud host and back through the tunnel.  The port forwarded on the router is already something weird but it is obviously being discovered.

Comment: Another technique is port knocking.  Where by you attempt to connect to a random sequence of ports, only you know, and the monitoring software would detect this sequence and let you in.  However, your modem is unlikely to support that natively so you would have to port forward all the ports used in the port knocking sequence to a computer,virtual or not, that is monitoring for that sequence.